# Can't find MVC3 Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010, and I can't seem to find the MVC3 template when creating a new project. I only have the MVC2 template, but most of these tutorials on the actual ASP.net website have MVC3 already installed.  Is there somewhere I need to go to add the template to my Visual Studio templates?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling MVC3 on your machine to see if it adds them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VS2010 shipped with MVC2.  You need to install MVC3 before you get the templates.  You can find the installer at http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3.

Answer (score 2):

Change the framework version to dot Net 4.0 and the templates should appear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on XP you need to install the Microsoft Windows SDK v7.0 otherwise the MVC templates won't show up in the project type list. The platform installer won't give you an error and the downloaded installer will tell you that the update is not applicable to your system without going to the details.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have VS2010 SP1, the MVC3 installation does not work (WPI or stand-alone).  There is a workaround documented here: http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2011/4/installing-asp-net-mvc3-on-visual-studio-2010-sp1/

Basically you download the stand-alone setup exe and extract and run the individual installers from it.

Answer (score 0):

The thing changed when programing with MVC. You should start your project with add new project not Add new web site